# how to start/proceed for implementing database layer for C#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

It's first time for me to start with something like this. In applications with decent size DLL (Data Logic Layer), BLL (Business Logic Layer) is common to implement.

But with no great experience around this area i am struggling regarding where to start. Most of the time i did simple application where to open connect, get data, close connections. And this is not good with application of good size. right ?

I visited some sites but Architectural aspects are not thoroughly covered, most of people focus on small issues/steps. So please provide inputs regarding how can is proceed, books, blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at what [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), like [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html), do.  I'm not saying they will be perfect for your situation but you can assess and make your own judgement.

- [Here is a more in depth overview of
  ORMs](http://www.objectmatter.com/vbsf/docs/maptool/ormapping.html)
- [and there are lots more resources here to help you learn the architectural aspects](http://www.objectarchitects.de/ObjectArchitects/orpatterns/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Russell is right. It is better to go with ORM like NHibernate or Codeplex ODX which helps to serve as a facade to Database and later create business library using the ORM to manage the business logic.

Unfortunately I also did not get the information about clean and enterprise coding standards until I started working in a large enterprise.

But the bottom line is all the enterprises uses the same mantra which is "DIVIDE AND RULE". In programming this is nice because it is easy to maintain, manage and break fix the application.